# Implementation of logout action

Tags: jsf, logout

is it correct way of implementing logout action? (is it wrong to use PostConstruct method?)

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Logout extends Root{

    @PostConstruct
    public void logout(){
        getSession().invalidate();
        try{
            getExternalContext().redirect("/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");        
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginBacking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            getContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, getBundle().getString("logoutError"), ex.getMessage()));
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `@RequestScoped` bean, not until requested to do so, cdi container will not even bother to create it. That said, i presume you would invoke `Logout.logout()` from your jsf page, if thats the case, why still use `@PostConstruct`? It performs no purpose, or rather, the call to Logout.logout() from your page will simply be a second invocation, after `@PostConstruct` was long invoked.

In simple terms, there is no need to use `@PostConstruct` here. Simple invocation of the `Logout.logout()` from jsf suffices.

Also, during jsf lifecycle, methods can be invoked severally, so when implementing `getSession()` for logout, be sure not to create another. otherwise you will be creating and destroying sessions multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, maress, i wanted to use just Logout instead of Logout.logout() in JSF view. is it correct way?

Comment: This is a @RequestScope, unless called upon to act, it wont be created. I presuppose the only way CDI will be able to create '@RequestScope' bean is if it is requested to do so, and the only way to do so is to require its use somewhere. So no, in this case you cannot use the '@PostConstruct' this way to logout, without really invoking any method of the bean

Comment: Thank you, i understood. I thought, i can make JSF to instantiate a bean just with #{Logout}.